# how to set nav-button to right with bootstrap twitter?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i want to set the button of "MID" at middle Page and "Right" at Right ..

[image]

this is my coding..i try to do with "style="float:right" but itsnot working..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Belajar BootStrap Twitter</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body background="img/vlcsnap-2013-12-23-14h06m41s77.png">
<div class="navbar" >
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-tonggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="dropdown-tonggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SubMenu <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a>sub_1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>nomor 2</a></li>
                            <li><a>nomor 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li >
                        <a>MID</a>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                   <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-inverse">
                    <li>
                        <a>Right</a>
                    </li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
</div>

            </body>

</html>
```

and how make a vertical line beside the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use class `pull-right`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-inverse pull-right">
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://bootply.com/112279)**

Comment: oh it works, where can i learn like this..?like w3schools.com

Comment: @akiong No, you can learn it directly from bootstrap docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html